# How do I copy files to "program files\\my application" for Windows Mobile (6.5) emulator?

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile-6.5

I am trying to test my mobile app and am not sure why I can't get my files deployed or copied to the emulator.

How can I deploy or add files to my applicaiton or program files directory?

EDIT
I am able to get this to work in some sense, but not the way I desire - I am able to either deploy or set the files as "copied" in their properties, but unfortunately if the files are updated the latest changes are NOT the ones "deployed" to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2008, In Project properties, Change the Output File Folder to whatever you want.

If you want to send the file  to that particular output Directory with or without change,

in File properties, change "Copy to output Directory" to copy always or copy if newer.